# How to clear field after sending in an AJAX contact form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

First, the code:

**CONTACT_FORM.HTML**

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Contact Form</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="contact_form.css" />
  <script src="contact_form.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="mainform">
   <form id="form" name="form" action="contact_form.html">
    <h3>Contact Form</h3>
    <p id="returnmessage"></p>
    <label>Name: <span>*</span></label>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name"/>
    <label>Email: <span>*</span></label>
    <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email"/>
    <label>Contact No: <span>*</span></label>
    <input type="text" id="contact" placeholder="10 digit Mobile no."/>
    <label>Message:</label>
    <textarea id="message" placeholder="Message......."></textarea>
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Send Message"/>
   </form>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**CONTACT_FORM.PHP**

```
<?php
 $name = $_POST['name1'];
 $email = $_POST['email1'];
 $message = $_POST['message1'];
 $contact = $_POST['contact1'];
 $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
 if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{10}$/", $contact)) {
   echo "<span>* Please Fill Valid Contact No. *</span>";
  } else {
   $subject = "Message from website...";
   $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
   $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
   $headers .= 'From:' . $email. "\r\n";
   $headers .= 'Cc:' . $email. "\r\n";
   $template = '<div style="padding:50px; color:white;">Hello ' . $name . ',<br/>'
   . '<br/>Thank you for contacting us.<br/><br/>'
   . 'Name:  ' . $name . '<br/>'
   . 'Email:  ' . $email . '<br/>'
   . 'Contact No:  ' . $contact . '<br/>'
   . 'Message:  ' . $message . '<br/><br/>'
   . 'This is a contact confirmation email.'
   . '<br/>'
   . 'We will keep you posted with our goings on.</div>';
   $sendmessage = "<div style=\"background-color:#7E7E7E; color:white;\">" . $template . "</div>";
   $sendmessage = wordwrap($sendmessage, 70);
   mail("me@mydomain.com", $subject, $sendmessage, $headers);
   echo "Thank you, your query has been received.";
  }
 } else {
  echo "<span>* invalid email *</span>";
 }
?>
```

**CONTACT_FORM.JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#submit").click(function() {
  var name = $("#name").val();
  var email = $("#email").val();
  var message = $("#message").val();
  var contact = $("#contact").val();
  $("#returnmessage").empty();
  if (name == '' || email == '' || contact == '') {
   alert("Please Fill Required Fields");
  } else {
   $.post("contact_form.php", {
    name1: name,
    email1: email,
    message1: message,
    contact1: contact
   }, function(data) {
    $("#returnmessage").append(data);
    if (data == "Your Query has been received, We will contact you soon.") {
     // $("#form")[0].reset();
     $('#form').find('form')[0].reset();
    }
   });
  }
 });
});
```

My questions are these...

1. How can I clear the form following submission?
2. Why is the CC back to the sender not functioning?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by `clear the form` ?

Comment: @Afaan: it looks like an AJAX form, and so the fields will contain the old information even after a successful sending.

Comment: OP, please use specific titles here, and ask one question per post. "Two questions about X" is not specific enough, and is not ideal either to attract help from readers or to accurately represent the topic to search engines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to charlietfl for pointing out the difference the text for the IF logic. Everything is working fine and dandy now.

As per charlietfl's suggestion, I changed the following line in my JS file:

OLD CODE:  $('#form').find('form')[0].reset();

NEW CODE:  $('#form')[0].reset();

Also, I modified the message text to be the same in the PHP and the JS so the IF statement would validate.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

As for the reset your code is trying to look inside one form to find another form ... that doesn't exist

Change

```
 $('#form').find('form')[0].reset();
```

To

```
 $('#form')[0].reset();
```

Comment: This didn't work. The form submits just fine and I receive the "Thank you" verbage, but the form does not clear following the submission. Thanks.

Comment: Your `if` condition text doesn't match what is sent from server

Comment: Crap! Can't believe I missed the difference in the text message for use with the IF statement. Thank you very much, charlietfl!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to clear the form from the top of my head:

In your HTML, add

```
<input type="reset" style="display:none;" id="reset-button" />
```

Then, in your JS:

```
if (data == "Your Query has been received, We will contact you soon.") {
 $('#reset-button').click();
}
```

About the CC part, why don't you use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/), it'll reduce your effort and be a lot easier to send to many recipients.

Comment: This suggestion didn't work. The form submits just fine and I receive the "Thank you" verbage, but the form does not clear following the submission. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear all text input elements.

```
$( "#form input:text" ).attr({value: ""});
```

Or to reset each field to the placeholder value:

```
$( "#form input:text" ).each(function(){
    var placeholder_value = $(this).attr('placeholder');
    $(this).attr('value', placeholder_value});
});
```

Comment: The first suggestion didn't work. The form submits just fine and I receive the "Thank you" verbage, but the form does not clear following the submission. The second suggestion prevents the form from sending anything...it does nothing when clicking the send button. Thanks.